# List view is not scrolling inside a scroll view

Tags: android, listview

i am using a list view inside a scroll view but the problem is that it is not scrolling when i dynamically add items to it here is my xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.social.socialapp"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#000000"
 android:fillViewport="true"
 android:scrollbars="none" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Your total balance :" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/creditYourCredit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="12"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.50"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="Daily free credit" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="50" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/creditClaimBT"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:background="#579df9"
            android:text="claim" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Note: Free credit expires in 14 days"
        android:textColor="#C0C0C0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/creditPremiumTV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.50"
            android:text="costs" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/creditPremiumMemberBT"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="#579df9"
            android:text="$ 1.99" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/creditAvailableOffersLV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/creditViewTableBT"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#777777"
            android:text="View credit table"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/creditViewCreditTableTB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <!-- Row 1 with single column -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#b0b0b0"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Costs Table"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Basic"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Premium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <!-- Row 2 with 3 columns -->

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableR1TV1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Basic Post"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableR1TV2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableR1TV3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableR2TV1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Urgent Post"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableR2TV2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableR2TV3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableR3TV1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Premium Post"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableR3TV2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableR3TV3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

what should i do i am not getting what i am doing wrong 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `ScrollView` that's only one solution

Comment: but my layout is too long it wont fit on screen

Comment: do i have any other option to do it with scroll view

Comment: Just remove ScrollView , ListView will fit your layout on screen , too. And it will be scrollable by itself.

Comment: i have many other things other than ListView

Answer (score 0):

ListViews are scrollable by themself. You dont have to put it inside a ScrollView.

Just remove the ScrollView and it should work.

Comment: i have to as my layout is too long and wont fit on the screen

Comment: then put your ListView in a LinearLayout